# Web-based code interpreter

Tags: interpreter

I remember coming across a website where I could type in some code and it would compile and run it (or error out), displaying any console output. It accepted a variety of interpreted and non-interpreted languages — I specifically remember that I could use C (maybe Python too... I'm not completely sure).

Does anyone know what site I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about http://codepad.org.

Answer (score 3):

maybe : http://ideone.com/